# The value is not assigned to label in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

The value is not assigned to lbl5

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim cc As String
    Dim an As String
    Dim da As Double
    Dim intam, tab As Double

    an = Val(txtan.Text)
    da = Val(txtxda.Text)
    cc = Val(txtcc.Text)


    If Val(txtan.Text) = "k" Then
        lbl5.Text = "hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh"
        intam = da * 0.05
    ElseIf an = "wanitha" Then
        intam = da * 0.06
    ElseIf an = "upahara" Then
        intam = da * 0.07


    End If

    tab = (da) + intam

End Sub
```

Comment: check txtan.Text...............

Comment: as per msdn Val function Returns the numbers contained in a string as a numeric value of appropriate type. so you need to change your logic

Answer (score 2):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

> The Val function returns the numbers contained in a string as a
>   numeric value of appropriate type. The Val function stops reading the
>   string at the first character it cannot recognize as part of a number

How can it be possible that this condition is true?

```
If Val(txtan.Text) = "k" Then
```

You should check with

```
If txtan.Text = "k" Then
```

also this is not quite right:

```
an = Val(txtan.Text)
```

should be

```
an = txtan.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

put a breakpoint in the line:

```
line If Val(txtan.Text) = "k" Then
```

and check if the comming value is really "k"

You also dont need to use Val(txtan.Text), txttan.Text is enough

Please be more specific in your next questions